# Prevent a process from creating a MessageBox

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

I have a problem with a system we're using with our application: Sometimes, when we ask this system for data he pops a MessageBox up to tell us something along the lines of: "I can't retrieve your data, there is way too much data to search for".

The problem with this is that the user may be unable to see or close the popup and thus this blocks the whole application (Explaining why the user cannot close/see the popup would take too much time and be off topic, that sucks but we've to deal with it).

So, as a temporary solution I would like to prevent this specific process from creating the MessageBox.

I've looked for a solution online and found about [CBTProc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644977(VS.85).aspx) which seems to provide a way to react to a particular Windows event (request from a process to create a window) and instruct the OS to block the request.

Is this the way to go?

I tested [SetWinEventHook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373640(v=vs.85).aspx) to detect process that request creation of a window and [DestroyWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632682(v=vs.85).aspx) to destroy the Window:

```
public class PopupWatchdog {

    #region constructor
    public PopupWatchdog() {
        SetWinEventHook(
            EVENT_OBJECT_CREATED,
            EVENT_OBJECT_CREATED,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            HookCallback,
            0, //id process
            0, //id thread
            WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT
        );
    }
    #endregion

    #region functions
    private static void HookCallback(IntPtr hWinEventHook, int iEvent, IntPtr hWnd, int idObject, int idChild, int dwEventThread, int dwmsEventTime) {
        Console.WriteLine("window {0} requests creating an object, trying to destroy it...", idChild);
        DestroyWindow(hWnd);
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWinEventHook(int eventMin, int eventMax, IntPtr hmodWinEventProc, HookProc lpfnWinEventProc, int idProcess, int idThread, int dwflags);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool DestroyWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
    #endregion

    #region events

    #endregion

    #region variables
    #region const
    private const int EVENT_OBJECT_CREATED = 0x8000;
    private const int WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT = 0;
    #endregion
    private delegate void HookProc(
        IntPtr hWinEventHook,
        int iEvent,
        IntPtr hWnd,
        int idObject, 
        int idChild,
        int dwEventThread, 
        int dwmsEventTime
    );
    #endregion
}
```

DestroyWindow cannot be used to destroy Window created by another Thread like msdn documentation says, which is understable. So my test were not successful. How can I work this out?

I may have made mistakes, I don't know Windows api well and just heard about CBTProc.

**Update**

I changed the code following @DavidHeffernan and @AlexK advices, and it works:

```
public class BlockingPopupWatchdog {
    #region ctor
    public BlockingPopupWatchdog(int processId) {
        _processId = processId;
    }
    #endregion

    #region functions
    internal bool Hook() {
        if (_hookId != IntPtr.Zero) {
            Unhook();
        }
        _hookId = SetWinEventHook(
            EVENT_OBJECT_CREATED,
            EVENT_OBJECT_CREATED,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            _hook,
            _processId, //id process
            0, //id thread
            WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT
        );

        if (_hookId == IntPtr.Zero) {
            Logger.Log(String.Format("Error {0} while hooking", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()), EventTypes.WARNING);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    internal bool Unhook() {
        if (_hookId == IntPtr.Zero) return false;
        if (!UnhookWinEvent(_hookId)) {
            Logger.Log(String.Format("Error {0} while unhooking", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()), EventTypes.WARNING);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    private static void HookCallback(IntPtr hWinEventHook, int iEvent, IntPtr hWnd, int idObject, int idChild, int dwEventThread, int dwmsEventTime) {
        if (hWnd == IntPtr.Zero) return;

        try {
            AutomationElement elem = AutomationElement.FromHandle(hWnd);
            if (elem == null || !elem.Current.ClassName.Equals(MESSAGEBOX_CLASS_NAME)) {
                return;
            }

            object pattern;
            if (!elem.TryGetCurrentPattern(WindowPattern.Pattern, out pattern)) return;

            WindowPattern window = (WindowPattern)pattern;
            if (window.Current.WindowInteractionState == WindowInteractionState.ReadyForUserInteraction) {
                window.Close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWinEventHook(int eventMin, int eventMax, IntPtr hmodWinEventProc, HookProc lpfnWinEventProc, int idProcess, int idThread, int dwflags);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool UnhookWinEvent(IntPtr hWinEventHook);
    #endregion

    #region variables
    #region const
    private const String MESSAGEBOX_CLASS_NAME = "#32770";
    private const int EVENT_OBJECT_CREATED = 0x8000;
    private const int WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT = 0;
    #endregion

    private delegate void HookProc(
        IntPtr hWinEventHook,
        int iEvent,
        IntPtr hWnd,
        int idObject,
        int idChild,
        int dwEventThread,
        int dwmsEventTime
    );

    private static readonly HookProc _hook = HookCallback;
    private IntPtr _hookId;
    private readonly int _processId;
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: There are quite a few mistakes in this code. You don't do any error checking, and you don't protect the delegate from GC by holding a reference in a static variable. Rather than calling `DestroyWindow`, I think you might post a `WM_QUIT` message to the dialog.

Comment: DestroyWindow is not appropriate, you could send a WM_CLOSE or use UIAutomation which is the better choice in that it can also be used to detect the message box creation without a hook.

Comment: Thank you both for your solutions, I will work on that and some back to you!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I updated the post following your advices, it works! I just have a last "problem": Windows seems to notify multiple times the creation of a MessageBox (3 times, with a different window handle (hWnd) each time) and the AutomationElement.FromHandle(hWnd) sometimes throws a ElementNotAvailableException: The target element corresponds to UI that is no longer available (for example, the parent window has closed). Also, is the code better now? I have close to no idea how to handle windows api exceptions

Comment: @AlexK. I didn't find the way to subscribe to an event when a window is created, could you put me in the right path? thank you (PS: couldn't put your name on my last comment but it was for you too)

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140303-00/?p=1623

Comment: Code looks better in that you keep the delegate alive. But you still don't check for errors. Did you read the documentation carefully. It tells you what to do. Look at the section that describes the return value.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan oh, I thought I had done that by checking return values of UnhookWinEvent and SetWinEventHook and log Marshal.GetLastWin32Error in case those values were not expected. I'll look for information about error handling with winapi and update the code when I know how to do that. Thanks

Comment: @AlexK. Nice! Exactly my problem, thanks!

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I was still looking at the first code. Your error handling looks good now.

Comment: @AlexK. Posted your solutions, thank you both!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to DavidHefferman and AlexK. here is the solutions that makes what I wanted.

Using WinApi:

```
public class BlockingPopupWatchdog {
    #region ctor
    public BlockingPopupWatchdog(int processId) {
        _processId = processId;
    }
    #endregion

    #region functions
    internal bool Hook() {
        if (_hookId != IntPtr.Zero) {
            Unhook();
        }
        _hookId = SetWinEventHook(
            EVENT_OBJECT_CREATED,
            EVENT_OBJECT_CREATED,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            _hook,
            _processId, //id process
            0, //id thread
            WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT
        );

        if (_hookId == IntPtr.Zero) {
            Logger.Log(String.Format("Error {0} while hooking", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()), EventTypes.WARNING);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    internal bool Unhook() {
        if (_hookId == IntPtr.Zero) return false;
        if (!UnhookWinEvent(_hookId)) {
            Logger.Log(String.Format("Error {0} while unhooking", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()), EventTypes.WARNING);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    private static void HookCallback(IntPtr hWinEventHook, int iEvent, IntPtr hWnd, int idObject, int idChild, int dwEventThread, int dwmsEventTime) {
        if (hWnd == IntPtr.Zero) return;

        try {
            AutomationElement elem = AutomationElement.FromHandle(hWnd);
            if (elem == null || !elem.Current.ClassName.Equals(MESSAGEBOX_CLASS_NAME)) {
                return;
            }

            object pattern;
            if (!elem.TryGetCurrentPattern(WindowPattern.Pattern, out pattern)) return;

            WindowPattern window = (WindowPattern)pattern;
            if (window.Current.WindowInteractionState == WindowInteractionState.ReadyForUserInteraction) {
                window.Close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWinEventHook(int eventMin, int eventMax, IntPtr hmodWinEventProc, HookProc lpfnWinEventProc, int idProcess, int idThread, int dwflags);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool UnhookWinEvent(IntPtr hWinEventHook);
    #endregion

    #region variables
    #region const
    private const String MESSAGEBOX_CLASS_NAME = "#32770";
    private const int EVENT_OBJECT_CREATED = 0x8000;
    private const int WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT = 0;
    #endregion

    private delegate void HookProc(
        IntPtr hWinEventHook,
        int iEvent,
        IntPtr hWnd,
        int idObject,
        int idChild,
        int dwEventThread,
        int dwmsEventTime
    );

    private static readonly HookProc _hook = HookCallback;
    private IntPtr _hookId;
    private readonly int _processId;
    #endregion
}
```

And the solution using UIAutomation:

```
private AutomationElement _watchedElement;
private void PopupOpenedHandler(Object sender, AutomationEventArgs args) {
    var element = sender as AutomationElement;
    if (element == null || !element.Current.ClassName.Equals(MESSAGEBOX_CLASS_NAME)) {
        return;
    }

    object pattern;
    if (!element.TryGetCurrentPattern(WindowPattern.Pattern, out pattern)) return;

    WindowPattern window = (WindowPattern)pattern;
    if (window.Current.WindowInteractionState == WindowInteractionState.ReadyForUserInteraction) {
        window.Close();
    }
}

internal bool Hook() {
    Process p = Process.GetProcessById(_processId);
    IntPtr wHnd = p.MainWindowHandle;
    if (wHnd != IntPtr.Zero) {
        _watchedElement = AutomationElement.FromHandle(wHnd);
        Automation.AddAutomationEventHandler (
            WindowPattern.WindowOpenedEvent,
            _watchedElement,
            TreeScope.Descendants,
            PopupOpenedHandler
        );
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


internal bool Unhook() {
    if (_watchedElement == null) return false;
    Automation.RemoveAutomationEventHandler(WindowPattern.WindowOpenedEvent, _watchedElement, PopupOpenedHandler);
    return true;
}
```